# Changing the order of the where clause is giving an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I try changing the order of SQL where condition, I am facing error.

for example:

```
select *
from dbo.abc
where measure_date <> 'null' and stage = 'xyz'
and measure_place = 'xxx' and fact_code = '123' and std_sis like '%180%'
and cast(measure_date as date) >= '2020/09/01' and cast(measure_date as date) <= '2020/10/13'
```

In the above query if I keep `std_sis` after `fact_code` I am getting output result whereas if I keep `std_sis` at the end of the query like:

```
select *
from dbo.abc
where measure_date <> 'null' and stage = 'xyz'
and measure_place = 'xxx' and fact_code = '123'
and cast(measure_date as date) >= '2020/09/01' and cast(measure_date as date) <= '2020/10/13'
and std_sis like '%180%'
```

I am getting error like:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: So you must be storing `measure_date` as a varchar instead of storing it as a proper date. And you have some invalid data in that column. The best thing is to stop using varchar for dates. The next best thing is to correct the invalid ones. The hack solution is to use try_convert and swallow the error.

Comment: @DaleK how its working by changing the where clause order ? you have any idea?

Comment: @PoovizhirajanN it changes the execution plan and SQL Server finds itself processing additional data before applying the `where` clause. Its a very common issue in SQL Server, where it accesses data it doesn't ultimately need.

Comment: @DaleK I think it is not an issue, it's a feature. It's lazy query execution. It will not check a condition until it has to.

Comment: @AminGheibi I didn't mean issue as in a problem - just as in something one has to cope with - especially if ones table contains invalid data.

Comment: By the way `measure_date <> 'null'` is not the same as `measure_date IS NOT NULL` - unless you are explicitly/literally putting the word 'null' into the field (which would then cause conversion errors as it's supposed to be a date) I imagine you'd want to use the IS NOT NULL version. You should also use universal dates e.g., `20200901` rather than `2020/09/01` - the latter may not work as desired with some settings.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are seeing is due to Short-circuiting by optimizer. but, it is not guaranteed. We can never predict that LEFT expression will be evaluated first and RIGHT expression will evaluated second.

To avoid this problem, you can do few things like below:

- Fix data issues in the measure_date. Only keep the date values
- You can change expression like below.

```sql
TRY_CAST(measure_date, DATE) >= '2020/09/01' AND TRY_CAST(measure_date, DATE)  <= '2020/10/13'
```

- Get the records which are date values and they apply filter

```sql
select * INTO #abc
from dbo.abc
where measure_date <> 'null' and stage = 'xyz'
and measure_place = 'xxx' and fact_code = '123' and std_sis like '%180%'
and isdate(measure_date) = 1

SELECT * FROM #abc
WHERE  cast(measure_date as date) >= '2020/09/01' and cast(measure_date as date) <= '2020/10/13'
```

[Read more on short-circuiting](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-t-sql-expression-short-circuiting)

Comment: AFAIK, your solution using a subquery suffers from the same problem as the original query. The query optimizer is not obligated to process the subquery first, then the outer query. Instead it will attempt to optimize the entire query. Using separate queries, i.e. one that filters and writes to a temporary table and a second that processes the temporary table, precludes having the query optimizer "help". Note that CTEs (without recursion) will also be optimized as one big query rather than as individual steps.

Answer (score 2):

As @DaleK has pointed out in the comments "the issue" is that you are casting a date stored as a string and the cast is invalid.

As pointed out in the comments the best solution is to change the table column type to date and fix all the bad data.

If you cannot not do this, then another option is to use [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (introduced in SQL 2012) function. This function returns `NULL` if a cast operation is invalid and does not throw an error.